# How to specify the principal end of a 1-1 relationship in code first mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a class:

```
public partial class CanteenTerminal : XTimeEntity
{
  public virtual Terminal Terminal { get; set; }
  public short TerminalId { get; set; }
}
```

and its mapping class:

```
public CanteenTerminalMap()
{
  // Primary Key
  HasKey(t => t.Id);

  // Table & Column Mappings
  ToTable("CANTEENTERM");
  Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("TERM_CODEID");

  // Relationships
  HasRequired(t => t.Terminal)
    .WithOptional(t => t.CanteenTerminal);
}
```

I also have class `Terminal`:

```
public partial class Terminal : XTimeEntity
{
  public Terminal()
  {
    ControllerInterfacePointers = new List<ControllerInterfacePointer>();
    TerminalParameters = new List<TerminalParameter>();
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Version { get; set; }
  public short Enabled { get; set; }
  public virtual CanteenTerminal CanteenTerminal { get; set; }
  public short CanteenTerminalId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<ControllerInterfacePointer> ControllerInterfacePointers { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<TerminalParameter> TerminalParameters { get; set; }
}
```

And its mapping file:

```
public TerminalMap()
{
  // Primary Key
  HasKey(t => t.Id);

  Property(t => t.Name)
      .IsRequired()
      .HasMaxLength(30);
  Property(t => t.Version)
      .HasMaxLength(8);

  // Table & Column Mappings
  ToTable("TERMINAL");
  Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("TERM_CODEID");
  Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("TERM_NAME");
  Property(t => t.Version).HasColumnName("TERM_VERSION");
  Property(t => t.Enabled).HasColumnName("TERM_ENABLED");
  Ignore(t => t.MasterId);
  Ignore(t => t.IsActive);

  HasOptional(t => t.CanteenTerminal)
    .WithRequired(t => t.Terminal);
}
```

Whenever the data model is built, i.e. when I run a test query, I get the following error. I get this for several one-to-one relationships, and I have just removed those properties from the entities temporarily just to avoid errors from entities I am not yet interested in.

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'XTime.Data.CanteenTerminal' and 'XTime.Data.Terminal'. The
>   principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using
>   either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Just how do I specify the principal end of the relationship?

Comment: After "withrequired(t => t.Terminal)" .withkey(--specify key here--).. I'm sorry, I do not have the tools to test it atm but I believe I solved this problem like this..

Comment: There is no `WithKey` option after the `WithRequired()` phrase in the fluent chain.

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToRequired) may be useful, though I doubt it applies to all versions of EF. If it's not supported, you will be looking for something like `HasOptional(t=>t.CanteenTerminal).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t=>t.CanteenTerminalId)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example of this type of problem here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#RequiredToRequired

The mapping for the primary keys here  is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>()
    .HasKey(t => t.InstructorID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.OfficeAssignment)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Instructor);
```

I did have to add an additional nav property (in the instructor class) in the sample, it seems to work ok:

```
// Navigation property 
public virtual OfficeAssignment OfficeAssignment { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a test, I would suggest something crazy:

```
public partial class Terminal : XTimeEntity
{
  public Terminal()
  {
    ControllerInterfacePointers = new List<ControllerInterfacePointer>();
    TerminalParameters = new List<TerminalParameter>();
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Version { get; set; }
  public short Enabled { get; set; }
  [Required] //I think this line will trick EF into liking you.
  public virtual CanteenTerminal CanteenTerminal { get; set; }
  public short CanteenTerminalId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<ControllerInterfacePointer> ControllerInterfacePointers { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<TerminalParameter> TerminalParameters { get; set; }
};
```